# Can't run rails console within Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, rails-console

I am attempting to learn how to use the rails console to help troubleshoot my rails app. However, the "Run IRB Console" and "Run Rails Console" are both grayed out within Rubymine, making it so I can't click them. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **Ruby** and **Rails** using **RVM** if you are in Ubuntu and if you are in Windows, Download Ruby and necessary **Devkit** and then from command prompt, install rails, and then try rails console option, if it works in the Terminal/cmd, it should work in RubyMine too.

Comment: I'm using a mac with the latest OS, and I did install ruby using the RVM. What is the rails console command I would type in terminal to test it? It sounds like perhaps I didn't install some necessary functionality for the rails console to operate correctly, from what you are saying.

Comment: `rails console` works from the terminal, if that is the command we are talking about.

Comment: Whats the output of the Rails c in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Rubymine is aware of your ruby and your gemset. You can specify these things in the settings page "Ruby SDK and Gems" in your RubyMine project settings.